# sparql - use of curly braces

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web

Hello I have a simple question regarding sparql queries.
does the curly braces have any effect in where clause ?
For ex:
Is there a difference between

```
{
  ?s1 ab:wasBornIn "Berlin".
  ?s1 ?p1 ?o1
}
{
  ?s2 ab:someProperty "SomeLiteral".
  ?s2 ?p2 ?o2
}
```

AND

```
{
  ?s1 ab:wasBornIn "Berlin".
  ?s1 ?p1 ?o1.
  ?s2 ab:someProperty "SomeLiteral".
  ?s2 ?p2 ?o2.
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### In many cases, there is no difference

In the examples that you gave, there's no difference.  This is actually called out in the specification:

> #### [5.2 Group Graph Patterns](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#GroupPatterns)
>
> In a SPARQL query string, a group graph pattern is delimited with
>   braces: {}. For example, this query's query pattern is a group graph
>   pattern of one basic graph pattern.
>
> ```
> PREFIX foaf:    <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
> SELECT ?name ?mbox
> WHERE  {
>           ?x foaf:name ?name .
>           ?x foaf:mbox ?mbox .
>        }
> ```
>
> The same solutions would be obtained from a query that grouped the
>   triple patterns into two basic graph patterns. For example, the query
>   below has a different structure but would yield the same solutions as
>   the previous query:
>
> ```
> PREFIX foaf:    <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
> SELECT ?name ?mbox
> WHERE  { { ?x foaf:name ?name . }
>          { ?x foaf:mbox ?mbox . }
>        }
> ```

### But there may be with filters

Where it would be possible to see a difference, though, is with filters:

> A constraint, expressed by the keyword FILTER, is a restriction on
>   solutions over the whole group in which the filter appears.

I think that means that

```
{ ?s ?p ?o1 }
{ ?s ?q ?o2
  filter( !isIri(?o1) )
}
```

is different from

```
{
  ?s ?p ?o1 .
  ?s ?q ?o2 .
  filter( !isIri(?o1) )
}
```

### Blank node labels

Another place where it might come into play is blank node labels:

> ### [5.1.1 Blank Node Labels](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#bgpBNodeLabels)
>
> When using blank nodes of the form _:abc,  labels for blank nodes are
>   scoped to the basic graph pattern.  A label can be used in only a
>   single basic graph pattern in any query.

The validator at sparql.org, for instance, will report a syntax error in:

```
select * where {
  { _:s ?p ?o }
  { _:s ?p ?o }
}
```

> Syntax error:
>
> ```
> Line 3, column 5: Blank node label reuse not allowed at this point: _:s
> ```

Comment: If there are other cases I've missed, be sure to call them out!